# IIS sporadically starts returning 503 errors and never recovers without an application pool restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

#### Goal

Find a means to get IIS to report the root cause of the 503 errors.

#### Problem

Sporadically in our production environment IIS will start reporting 503 errors for every end point in our ASP.NET MVC website. Once this starts it doesn't seem to recover without restarting the application pool. It is worth noting that in IIS manager the application pool **is still running** and I have refreshed many times as a sanity check.

#### Settings

I scrubbed these files before uploading them to remove anything sensitive so if a username and password are missing that should be a red herring.

- [Machine.config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8o2562zzl1wkf8y/Machine.config?dl=0)
- [Web.config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ujj9ql8ktppyn0/Web.config?dl=0)

#### Remote Diagnostics

- Looked at logging all our exceptions but this returned nothing that stuck out. We can see exceptions are being thrown but they are also being handled.
- Looked at errors in the event log and their are no errors for IIS, ASP.NET, or the .NET Runtime. I looked through the rest of the event log and was unable to find anything that stuck out. I also talked to our systems team about making sure it had privileges to write to the event log just to be safe.
- Turned failed request tracing on and examined the logs. I was only able to find a message saying `Operation completed successfully` that caused a 500. I haven't explicitly found any documentation saying that is correct but I assume to `Operation completed successfully` is referring to reporting to issue to the client.
- Examined the traffic from our proxy to the load balanced servers hosting the sites. We are using HAProxy and I was using Graylog to aggregate and examine the data. Even at peak hours of traffic nothing was taking more than a few milliseconds but once the issue happens many requests will backup at HAProxy and start slowing down considerably. The end points seem to have no correlation to the problem and even when I look at the first request to kick off the problem they are not always the same.

#### Local Diagnostics

I tried these cases to see if I could produce the symptoms we are seeing in production on my local machine.

- Manually threw a `ThreadAbortException`. In the event of the thread abort the failed request log was the same but the Application Pool was stopped so this was not the same symptoms in production.
- Set the application pool Queue Length to 10 (production and my local machine are 1000). Then used JMeter to pound my local machine with ~800 request/second. This caused the exact same symptoms. Unfortunately even introducing a second worker (our production has 2 works and is load balanced) caused this issue to no longer manifest. I have not found a means yet to determine if we are hitting a limit on the Queue Length. I have looked at performance counters but they do not seem to match up with the traffic I am seeing in GrayLog.

In closing the only thing that has even seemed remotely close to what I have seen in production is case 2 of my local diagnostics. Regardless though I have not found a means to get IIS to produce a log with information indicating this.

Comment: You need an IIS memory dump when the issue is occurring, only way to know what's happening. If I were to guess, it's either a memory leak or threading. You can also check app pool memory and CPU usage at the time for more info. High memory indicative of memory leak while normal memory and low CPU indicative of a threading issue. Those are just clues though, you'll need to debug memory dump to be sure.

Comment: During the times this is occurring we are seeing low CPU usage and Memory. I don't have exact numbers but I was told the w3wp.exe is still using CPU and Memory but no more than normal. We have installed the remote debugger in production and that is the next step we will be taking when it happens.

Comment: Remote debugging can potentially help depending on the issue but won't help for some errors. Give remote debugging a shot and if it doesn't help, go the memory dump route.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I started using windbg a while ago until we got a symbol server setup. At that point I just started debugging the memory dumps directly in Visual Studio. Do you happen to know the draw backs/advantages to debugging memory dumps in Visual Studio?

Comment: The power of windbg is the plugins, the main one being sos. sos can be used, but not completely in visual studio and it is also a bit of a pain to do so. There are also other plugins like mex which Visual Studio doesn't appear to support. There is a bit of a learning curve the first time you use windbg with sos, but after doing it a couple times, you can very quickly diagnose issues such as yours (I'm talking like <10 minutes) and you get full plugin support.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning So this seems to be some kind of locking issue in the mysql connector 6.6.4. Essentially their is a lock around the hashtable for connection pooling and we are getting so many requests that they are backing up waiting to get past the lock. If you would like to submit and answer for using windbg to diagnose the issue and it being a threading issue I will accept it. Also thanks for your help with windbg.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You said "low CPU indicative of a threading issue". Did you mean high to say that high CPU is indicative of a threading issue?

Comment: @aw1975 what I've seen typically, is that when CPU is low but system is deadlocked, it is due to threading. What happens is that threads have contention and once that occurs, no work can be done so CPU won't be utilized. When you have a high CPU situation, typically means threads are doing work (too much work in fact) which usually doesn't point to thread contention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with issues whose fix is an `IIS RESTART` or recycling the IIS application pool, I'd recommend downloading [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools), creating a memory dump of your IIS application pool when it is in the problematic state and going from there. Generally speaking for the above issues, analyzing a memory dump is the best way to go and one way you can be sure as to what the issue.